# How to find all initialized classes in visual studio 2015 using regex?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to find all my initialized classes in visual studio, such as:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass() 
{
};
```

But so far no good news:(

Tried so far: `{class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]*}` and it's not working:(

Comment: Regular expressions aren't the way to do this.  You need a grammar.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to edit all my initialized classes, and i need to find them all..

Comment: In VS, go to Edit>Find and Replace>Find in Files, then enter " = new " (include the spaces, but not the quotes).

Comment: Exactly.  Use an IDE.  That's what they're for.

Comment: This is a job for [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the expected answer and maybe stupid but what if you search for `_new_` (with spaces around and for "whole word, case sensitive"? You'll find them all! But with some noise from comments or internal types like `new SqlParameter()`